# Laravel 5.2 JWTAuth and Auth::user()

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-5

I am using this great library JWTAuth and i want to use Laravels Auth:: functions like so..

```
public function signup(Request $request)
{

   // dd(Auth::check());

    $all = $request->all();

    $rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name'  => 'required|min:3',
        'email'      => 'email|required|max:255|unique:type_user',
        'password'   => 'required|min:6',
    ];

    if(!Auth::check()){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->get('personal_information'), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json( $validator->messages() , 422);
        }

        $personal_information = [
            'first_name' => $request['personal_information']['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $request['personal_information']['last_name'],
            'email'      => $request['personal_information']['email'],
            'password'   => bcrypt($request['personal_information']['password']),
        ];
        $user = User::create($personal_information);
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);


        //$authId = Auth::user()->id;
       // $authId = $user->id;

        unset($all['personal_information']);
    }else{
        $authId = Auth::user()->id;
    }


}
```

but i cant seem to get the Auth:: functions to work.

i have also this in __construct:

```
$this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate','signup']]);
```

so i understand that because of `signup` beeing exluded then something is beeing skipped for Auth:: to be available.

edit: I have succesfully used Auth:: functions in another controller method after the signup. but how to use it inside signup?

please say if more code needed